# What is the most cited mathematical paper?

Tags: math-history, big-list

Just out of curiosity:

```
What is the paper with the largest number of citations in all of mathematics?
```

I think it is Shannon's *A Mathematical Theory of Communication* (with its 71025 citations, according to Google Scholar), but I don't know any official sources about this.

```
What are other papers with a large number of citations?
```

(I am aware that the number of citations does not measure the importance of a work; this question is only for the sake of curiosity.)

Comment: Interesting question !

Comment: Please more answers - bonus open worth 50 score points. :)

Comment: Shannon's paper kicking off information theory is a good candidate. In general, the applied and engineering side of math seems to cite and get cited a lot more than the pure side.

Comment: I suspect that the (big-list) tag somehow contradicts the query for *the* most cited paper

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen; i think he means the most cited paper in each mathematical discipline.

Comment: [Question at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/199978/the-most-cited-paper-in-mathematics).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: you are right. The (big-list) tag is there just for the second question.

Comment: What is mathematical? And cited where? Does the internet count?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: mathematical = within to the scope of mathematics and written in mathematical language. I do not know if one can determine easily where most citations of a paper come from (e.g. on Google Scholar). I would like to count only citations from other papers of mathematics if possible.

Answer (score 10):

According to the list in [this article](http://www.nature.com/news/the-top-100-papers-1.16224), the most cited math paper is "Fuzzy Sets" by Zadeh. But the article also links to the top 100 most-cited papers by Google Scholar's count; the most-cited math paper on that list is "A Mathematical Theory of Communication."

Answer (score 3):

Using MathSciNet/Math Reviews would give one way of settling "what is mathematical," but I don't see a way to search for the maximum "citations from references."  Perusing the list of top citation recipients from 2014 gives a candidate with 1365 such citations:

MR0370183 (51 #6412) 
Ambrosetti, Antonio; Rabinowitz, Paul H.
Dual variational methods in critical point theory and applications. 
J. Functional Analysis 14 (1973), 349–381.

The Claude Shannon piece mentioned by Mizar has 829 citations from references in MR.